# Combine HAL libraries and mbed libraries on same project

Tags: driver, stm32, hal, mbed

I am working on an existing project which is implemented in nucleo STM32l476RG. The project uses mbed 2 libraries as shown in the following image.

[image]

In order to integrate a new function on the existing project I must use HAL libraries which do not come from mbed.
[image]

When I add Drivers file It is obvius that I get conflict for Hal pointing to same naming functions. Is it possible to use specific Hal either from drivers or from mbed on same project?